# RxJS compare to last and emit

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm rather new to ReactiveJS and I would like to achieve the following:

Only emit a value (object) if it has a different timestamp (updated_at) from the last one.

```
var checkJobsRx = new Rx.Subject();
checkJobsRx
.dosomethinghere()
.subscribe(function (data) {})
```

Comment: No clue about RxJs, but in Bacon you can pass a predicate function to `skipDuplicates`. Is there `skipDuplicates` in RxJS?

Comment: Apparently it's called `distinct` in RxJs: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, read the documentation about **distinctUntilChanged()**. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html

I guess the following code is the answer for the question.(just 1 line added)

```
var checkJobsRx = new Rx.Subject();
  checkJobsRx
 .dosomethinghere()
 .distinctUntilChanged(function(job) { return job.updated_at })
 .subscribe(function (data) {})
```

Comment: specific docs about `distinctUntilChanged()` also found here : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinctuntilchanged.md

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinctUntilChanged` to have your check the emitted values for duplicates:

```
checkJobsRx
  .map(fooBar)
  .distinctUntilChanged((item) => item.updated_at)
  .subscribe((data) => { })
```

Check [the documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html)

Comment: It is a fine print, but `distinctUntilChanged` would be closer to the requirement of `a different timestamp (updated_at) from the LAST one.`. `distinct` filters out reoccuring values, independently of whether they occur in immediate succession.

Comment: This is exactly why I updated the answer a while ago :)